# Come and See Me Sometime!

Tags: riddle

I arise well after 3
and there are 9 that make me.

My world has random form.
For me, too, that's the norm.

I feel incomplete and I know that I am.
Please look me up sometime. This isn't a scam.

I'll provide some ID
with high hopes you'll agree.

246-89-0641

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the location of e in the number pi?

I used an internet search, I guess that's cheating.  No way that I would have gotten it otherwise.  This is the link that got me there:

> https://twitter.com/iquilezles/status/744731092465254400

Comment: You are SO SO CLOSE! Hurry up dude! Get the answer!!!!!!!!!!!!!! HURRY!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Some will argue I should give you full credit now!

Comment: I will give you full credit. The answer is 271828182 and appears at the 246,890,641st decimal digit of Pi. The following is amazing. Apparently, it may be possible for full-blown "e" to appear in Pi. How can it be?!?!? Cheers from the USA my friend.

Answer (score 5):

Are you perhaps..

> A social security number (SSN)/the social security system in the United States?

I arise well after 3

> According to Wikipedia, over 25 million numbers were issued in the first three months, which is still a fraction of the entire population. Hence it would take well over 3 (months) for the system as it is today to arise.

and there are 9 that make me.

> A social security number has 9 digits.

My world has random form. For me, too, that's the norm.

> Any one SSN looks like a random string of numbers.

I feel incomplete and I know that I am.

> Not everyone in the United States has one due to religious objections, etc.

Please look me up sometime. This isn't a scam.

> It is important to know your SSN. Also, as with pretty much any country-wide identification system, it has been used for and in scams.

I'll provide some ID with high hopes you'll agree. 246-89-0641

> Google tells me that this is an example of an SSN.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A good try, but not what I was looking for. This is my first puzzle, so I don't exactly know when to begin providing clarifying hints.

Comment: @Inquisitive It's fine, I didn't believe this was the best fit anyway :P In Puzzling, normally people provide hints if others ask, or after 2 to 3 days to account for timezones and work and stuff.